# Django CSV download with checkbox forms

Tags: django, csv

Before the actual download, i have some checked entries to be considered, so i only have the checked in the CSV file.

the checked input.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checked" value="{{ row.CI }}" class="checkboxAll"></td>
```

1. 

if i try using form submit, i get these checked, but then the CSV view "return response" clears the form, so i cant submit twice if needed.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn " value="csv_download" name="csv_download" onclick="this.form.submit();">
<a class="fa-solid fa-file-csv" style="padding-left: 5px; font-size: 9px;" href="#">&nbsp csv_form</a>            
</button>
```

2. 

if i try using classic CSV-file download using URL, then i do not get these checked because the form is not submitted.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn ">
<a class="fa-solid fa-file-csv" style="padding-left: 5px; font-size: 9px;" href="{% url 'download_csv' %}?{{request.GET.urlencode}}">&nbsp csv_download</a>
</button>
```

the view for 1.

def v_base(request):

```
if request.GET.get('csv_download'):

    print("call csv_download")
    response = download_csv(request)
    return response # if using 1. then the form i cleared and download cant be clicked twice or more
```

the View.py for 2.

```
download_csv(request):
    
    checked = request.GET.getlist('checked') # this is not received if using 2.

    db_sel_columns, column = get_column_selected(request)
    rows = Vbase.objects.all().values(*db_sel_columns)
    rows_filter = baseFilter(request.GET, queryset=rows)
    rows_count = rows_filter.qs.count()
 

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=download.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(db_sel_columns) # write header
    for row in rows_filter.qs:
        writer.writerow([row['CI'],row['Description']])

    return response
```

have anybody an idea to how i come around this?

Comment: can you add  `get_column_selected` function? and I see nothing to do with `checked` in the function

Comment: get_column_selected is just a function where i keep which columns the user has in use. (should have omitted it here ) They are in a table, and therefore it gives no problem. it the checked from the html form that is not passed when using 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
<td><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checked" value="{{ row.CI }}" class="checkboxAll"></td>

<button type="button" id="submit" class="btn">
<a class="fa-solid fa-file-csv" style="padding-left: 5px; font-size: 9px;">&nbsp csv_form</a>            
</button>
```

add to head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

add to bottom of body:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Follow Action 
            $('#submit').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POS",
                    url: "{% url 'download_csv' %}",
                    
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRFToken': '{{csrf_token}}'
                    },
                    data: {'checkbox': $('#checkbox').prop('checked')},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response) { 
                       console.log(response)                            
                    },
                    error: function(rs, e) {
                       console.log('error')
                    }
                }); 
        });
        </script>
```

view

```
download_csv(request):
    
    checked = request.GET.get('checkbox')
    print(checked, '*'*10)
    db_sel_columns, column = get_column_selected(request)
    rows = Vbase.objects.all().values(*db_sel_columns)
    rows_filter = baseFilter(request.GET, queryset=rows)
    rows_count = rows_filter.qs.count()
 

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=download.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(db_sel_columns) # write header
    for row in rows_filter.qs:
        writer.writerow([row['CI'],row['Description']])

    return response
```

Comment: url: "{% url 'follow' %}", is my url to download? like:  url: "{% url 'download_csv' %}",

Comment: yes you need to give your url name. I have updated the answer already

Comment: im working on it. i have some trouble with the url. its translated wrong. its adding csv_download as part of the url.

Comment: @user625079 it is because of your submit button remove value from it like I did in my ansert

Comment: i got it to send. but the json must be received from body. but when i read it i the view, it will not be read by "data = json.loads(request.body)". according to diff posts i do not need to decode in django 4.1

Comment: i solved the last problem. you have to write data not as data: { 'checked' : checkedCheckboxesAtoJSON }, but like   data:  checkedCheckboxesAtoJSON, then i can read it in the view as     received_json_data = json.loads(request.body)